# Why do enum constants but not members in struct declarations have file scope?

Tags: c, struct, scope

If I have

```
struct example
{
  enum {A, B} letter;
  int number;
} eg;
```

I may use the `A` or `B` anywhere else in the file due to the fact that the `{...}` after `example` do not constitute a block because the brackets may only contain declarations, not statements. Thus, the `enum` constants are located outside any block and by 6.2.2/4 of the C standard, they have file scope.

However, if I type `number` in `main`, I get an undeclared error. I understand this intuitively: we think of `number` as only existing as a member of `example`, requiring an instance of the structure to access it. Now, this intuition fails for the enumeration constants as I do not have to type `eg.A` to access the value of `A`, but intuition is immaterial if this syntax follows from the C standard.

Therefore, my question is: from which clauses in the C standard does it follow that I have to write `eg.number` to access `number`?

Comment: I think you might flip it around - there's nowhere in the standard that defines any meaning for `number` in other contexts than `eg.number` (with exceptions like `offsetof` and so forth).

Comment: How about 6.2.3

Comment: @user3386109 that was my first suspicion but it only says that if "more than one declaration of a particular identifier is visible...". In the example, there is only one declaration of `number` (which should be visible in `main` since it is in file scope). I am not sure of 6.2.3 applies.

Comment: @NateEldredge but I cannot reconcile that with the fact that `int number` is a declaration for `number` with file scope. I don't know how to "derive" a difference for the `enum` and `int number` from the clauses.

Comment: I noticed that as well, but I think the word **"Thus"** in the second sentence overrides the word **"If"** in the first sentence. In other words, the **"If"** clause only applies to the second half (after the comma) of the first sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not scope so much as name space.

C 2018 6.2.3 1 says there are separate name spaces for:

- labels (used with `goto`);
- tags of structures, unions, and enumerations (the tag is the name after `struct`, `union`, or `enum`, as in `struct foo`);
- members of structures or unions (and each structure or union has a separate name space for its members); and
- all other identifiers.

Since `struct example { … int number; }` declares `number` as a member of `example`, it is in the name space of `struct example`, so the only place it is recognized as a member of `struct example` is in the context of a member of `struct example`, as in `x.number`, where `x` is an expression of type `struct example`.

The `enum` member names `A` and `B` fall into the “all other identifiers” category above, so they are recognized wherever ordinary identifiers may be used.

Both the `enum` member names and the `struct` member names have file scope (given that this declaration appears outside any function), as may be seen by writing code later in the file that uses any of them. For example, if, later in the source file, `p` is a `struct example *`, then the compiler will accept `p->number`, and it will refer to the `number` member of `p`, demonstrating that `number` has file scope.

Comment: Thank you. Does the C standard formally define a name space? In particular, I am struggling to understand "so the only place it is recognized as a member of `struct example` is in the context of a member of `struct example`, as in `x.number`, where `x` is an expression of type `struct example`". Does this follow from any clauses in the C standard or is it just a more general concept in programming?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: The fact that separate name spaces exist is specified in the paragraph I cited, 6.2.3 1. The C standard does not explicitly state which name space is used for looking up identifiers at specific points in the grammar except to say, in 6.2.1 5, “Unless explicitly stated otherwise, where this document uses the term "identifier" to refer to some entity (as opposed to the syntactic construct), it refers to the entity in the relevant name space whose declaration is visible at the point the identifier occurs.” …

Comment: … So it is simply evident from context that if the grammar calls for an ordinary identifier at some point, it is looked up in the “all other identifiers” name space, and if it calls for a member name, as after the “.” and “->” operators, it is looked up in the associated structure or union name space, and if it is after a `goto`, it is looked up in the label name space, and so on.

Comment: Also, in preprocessing there is one name space for macros. This is separate from the name spaces used in the main translation.

Comment: I just identified another point of confusion. I did not understand what differentiated the `int number` from the `A` or `B` in the `enum` as in "why is `A` not in the name space of `struct example`". Is this because `{A, B}` is actually a list of independent declarators itself that is just part of the type specifier for `letter`? In this case, `letter` is in the name space of the structure, but the constants are not, because they are declared as part of the type specifier. Is this correct?

Comment: @GuachoPerez: The identifiers in an enumerator list are declared as constants, called enumeration constants. They are not members of a structure or union. Members are the objects declared within a structure or union. (The items in an enumeration declaration are not declarators. The contents of `{…}` in an `enum` declaration is a list of *enumerator* items, each of which is either an *enumeration-constant* or *enumeration-constant* `=` *constant-expression*. An *enumeration-constant* is an *identifier*.)